# making a toy unix os : issues with ld

Tags: compiling

So I'm following this tutorial on [rolling out your own toy unix](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html).

I'm stuck at compiling the sample source on [this page](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/2.-Genesis.html). This is a download link to the [sample source code](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/downloads/genesis.tar)

The Makefile looks like this:

```
SOURCES=boot.o main.o
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector
LDFLAGS=-Tlink.ld
ASFLAGS=-felf

all: $(SOURCES) link
clean:
    -rm *.o kernel
link:
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o kernel $(SOURCES)
.s.o:
    nasm $(ASFLAGS) $<
```

On OSX I couldn't manage to `make` because [Apple's ld](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html) doesn't support a `-T` switch. I tried compiling on CentOS and I got this:

```
[gideon@centosbox src]$ make 
nasm -felf boot.s
cc -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector   -c -o main.o main.c
main.c:4: warning: 'struct multiboot' declared inside parameter list
main.c:4: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
ld -Tlink.ld -o kernel boot.o main.o
boot.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
make: *** [link] Error 1
```

Of course my only problem is `File in wrong format.`

What does this mean? How do I correct it?

Comment: use `objdump -f` with the objects `*.o` to see what format they are. [about the -T flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051689/using-a-linker-script-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: *maybe* you can get a similar result using `-segaddr` `-seg_page_size` `-sectalign` [ld](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ld.1.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These sound like you're mixing code for different architectures. See here: [could not read symbols, file in wrong format](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-695836-view-next.html?sid=e4af4b67b66d23a4d12a134509c01a46).

*excerpt*

> You get that error when you change architectures. Are those CHOST/CFLAGS settings new?

#### Questions

- I wonder if the Toy Unix OS can only be built on x86 and not x64. Something to look into.
- `make clean`. Did the files you're using on CentOS come from OSX in any way?
- I see `boot.o` being used but don't see it being compiled, unless the `nasm -felf boot.s` builds it, so perhaps it's the OSX version of this file.

#### The fix

If you take a look at the options for `nasm` you'll notice that it's using the switches:

```
$ nasm -felf boot.s
```

The `elf` format is a 32-bit format. On newer systems that are 64-bit you need to change this to `elf64`. You can see these formats using the `nasm -hf` option:

```
$ nasm -hf
...
valid output formats for -f are (`*' denotes default):
  * bin       flat-form binary files (e.g. DOS .COM, .SYS)
    ith       Intel hex
    srec      Motorola S-records
    aout      Linux a.out object files
    aoutb     NetBSD/FreeBSD a.out object files
    coff      COFF (i386) object files (e.g. DJGPP for DOS)
    elf32     ELF32 (i386) object files (e.g. Linux)
    elf64     ELF64 (x86_64) object files (e.g. Linux)
    as86      Linux as86 (bin86 version 0.3) object files
...
```

So changing this line in the Make file:

```
ASFLAGS=-felf64
```

and re-running `make`:

```
$ make
ld -Tlink.ld -o kernel boot.o main.o
$
```

solves the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about `(1)`, I will find out. `(2)` I did do a make clean. `(3)` : Yea, seems like there aren't instructions on how to build `boot.o`. Thanks for your answer, I'm somewhat new to this stuff.

Comment: @gideon - np. I hadn't heard of this OS before either, will be checking it out as well, looked interesting in learning a lot of the basics.

Comment: @gideon - I just tried it and get the same error as you. BTW the line `nasm -felf boot.s` builds `boot.o`.

Comment: so are you saying that it only will compile on an x86 machine ?

Comment: @gideon - i figured it out. See updates.